# Django webapp not working on ipad(csrf_token) and IE(CORS) error

Tags: python, django, internet-explorer, csrf-token

Sorry, I know this is kind of 2 quetions in one, but there may be a resource out there that can fix both my problems. I have a webapp that I have created with Django that I am loading into an iframe of a wordpress site that I have started testing.

At the moment it works as designed on google chrome, my android phone, and iphones. However I am having a CSRF token issue when I 'POST' from the iframe only when using an ipad.

I am also not able to load in internet explorer, getting a CORS error after going through the "django-cors-headers" documentation.

I have both X-frame-options and Cors whitelist allowing the site to host the iframe.

I am lost as to why the app can work fine in a couple of settings and not in others - or if the errors may just be due to individualized settings on the devices I am testing on. If anyone can help in any way it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework), checking if you have followed all the steps of using django-cors-headers library. Please also check the Django version you use, the library **doesn't support** **Django version < 1.11**. And in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880593/django-cors-headers-cors-origin-whitelist-tuple-vs-string-issue), it shows that CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST works fine as a string but not as a tuple. Please confirm that you have used the right form.

For the CORS error in IE, the server must attach the following headers to all responses, you could check [this article](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests) for more information. You could also refer to [this blog](https://medium.com/@mozak104/how-to-solve-ie-edge-cors-error-f52e57778252) which provides another way to handle the CORS issue in IE.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: DAV, content-length, Allow
```